# What should be the host file configuration for Cloudera Installation for 5 nodes?

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am trying to install Cloudera cluster on 5 machines- 4 as ubuntu 12.04 and 1 as Oracle Enterprise Linux 5.8. 
I have run the Cloudera Manager Installer on Oracle Linux Enterprise host which should act as a name node ( with ip address 192.168.1.185) and other 4 Ubuntu hosts should act as data nodes.
I have completed all the prerequisites and I have configured host files as:

For Ubuntu:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.1.181   hduser1.example.co.in    hduser1
192.168.1.182   hduser2.example.co.in    hduser2
192.168.1.183   hduser3.example.co.in    hduser3
192.168.1.184   hduser4.example.co.in    hduser4
192.168.1.185   hduser5.example.co.in    hduser5


#The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

For Oracle Enterprise Linux:

```
192.168.1.181   hduser1.example.co.in    hduser1
192.168.1.182   hduser2.example.co.in    hduser2
192.168.1.183   hduser3.example.co.in    hduser3
192.168.1.184   hduser4.example.co.in    hduser4
192.168.1.185   hduser5.example.co.in    hduser5
127.0.0.1               hduser5.example.co.in hduser5 localhost.localdomain loca$
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

I am not sure whether this configuration is correct as i have got errors related to reverse DNS as follows:

```
The following failures were observed in checking hostnames. Showing first 1000 failures only...

DNS reverse lookup of IP 192.168.1.184 on host hduser1.example.co.in failed. Expected hduser4.example.co.in but got hduser4.local.
DNS reverse lookup of IP 192.168.1.182 on host hduser1.example.co.in failed. Expected hduser2.example.co.in but got hduser-desktop-3.local.
DNS reverse lookup of IP 192.168.1.183 on host hduser1.example.co.in failed. Expected hduser3.example.co.in but got hduser-desktop.local.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research I found that the host file configuration is correct. The problem due compatibility issues between Ubuntu and Oracle Enterprise Linux. After switching all the nodes to Ubuntu the issue was resolved.
Also I edited resolv.conf of all hosts. The configuration was as follows:

```
domain  example.co.in
search  example.co.in    localdomain
nameserver 192.x.x.x
```